Understanding the proof of Hahn-Banach in the case of Hilbert space
From this post a bounded linear functional on a closed linear subspace of a Hilbert space has a unique norm preserving extension.
Then I go through a proof of Hahn-Banach ($\tilde V = V + \langle w\rangle,\|\phi\|=1,\phi:V\to\Bbb R$):

$\cdots\cdots$
There will be such a $\lambda$ if, and only if,
$$
-\|v+w\|-\phi(v) \leqslant\left\|v^{\prime}+w\right\|-\phi\left(v^{\prime}\right)
$$
for all $v, v^{\prime} \in V$. Indeed, we could then take any $\lambda \in[m, M]$ with
$$
m:=\sup _{v \in V}-\|v+w\|-\phi(v), \quad M:=\inf _{v^{\prime} \in V}\left\|v^{\prime}+w\right\|-\phi\left(v^{\prime}\right) .
$$
Rearranging, the inequality we are required to prove is
$$
\phi\left(v^{\prime}\right)-\phi(v) \leqslant\left\|v^{\prime}+w\right\|+\|v+w\|
$$
for all $v, v^{\prime} \in V$. However the left-hand side is $\phi\left(v^{\prime}-v\right)$ which, since $\|\phi\|=1$, has magnitude at most $\left\|v^{\prime}-v\right\|$. The result is now a consequence of the triangle inequality.

If $V$ is a Hilbert space, by uniqueness $\lambda$ must be $0$, we should have $m=M=0$.
I try to see it directly from the definition of $m,M$:
$$0=\sup _{v \in V}-\|v+w\|-\phi(v)=\inf _{v^{\prime} \in V}\left\|v^{\prime}+w\right\|-\phi\left(v^{\prime}\right) .\tag1$$
Since $V$ is Hilbert, $\phi$ attains its norm $1$ on the unit sphere: $\exists u\in V,\|u\|=1,\phi(u)=1$.
Let $v=-|v|u,v'=|v'|u$ and let $|v|\to\infty,|v'|\to\infty$, then $(1)$ becomes
$$0=\lim_{|v|\to\infty}-\|-|v|u+w\|+|v|=\lim_{|v'|\to\infty}\left\||v'|u+w\right\|-|v'|.\tag2$$
Is this true?
